# How to deploy a django project to google cloud with celery workers?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, task-queue, celery-task

So i have a django project which I installed celery and heroku redis for it and I use google cloud for deployment. Everything works fine at local but i need to run my celery workers on website 24/7. I searched for supervisor and installed it too. I start supervisor from my command line. Celery workers runs since I ran supervisor. But there is a problem. I can not hold my pc open all the time. When I close, supervisor stops too. I did not figured out cloud tasks as well. Lastly, I read some infos about kubernetes and celery. Is it possible to use celery with kubernetes and how can i install kubernetes-celery django setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be running your Django server with Gunicorn, your Redis service as a separate service, and your celery worker as a third service.

Alternatively, if you want one single container instance (Pod in k8s) you can set a supervisor to run gunicorn and your celery worker inside the same pod

Comment: So what should i do? learn docker and k8s? because ita too hard to understand.

Comment: You don't need k8s. Docker yes would be good.

Comment: is google app engine enough for containerized app deploy?

Comment: @stratovic Yeah. It actually containerizes it on its own if you set the environment. You can set a "custom" environment if you want it to build your own dockerfile